# Links browser "SSL error"

Tags: macos, ssl, openssl, links

I have macos 10.10 Yosemite on my laptop and i configured links with this command:

`./configure --x-includes=/usr/X11/include --x-libraries=/usr/X11/lib/ --with-ssl --enable-graphics`

Output was:

```
Configuration results:

Event handler:      NO
IPv6:           YES
Supported compression:  ZLIB BZIP2
SSL support:        OPENSSL
UTF-8 terminal:     YES
GPM support:        NO
Graphics enabled:   YES
Graphics drivers:   X
Font rendering:     INTERNAL
Image formats:      GIF PNG XBM
OpenMP:         NO
```

But when I open https sites, I have this error:

```
Error loading https://duckduckgo.com/lite:
SSL error.
```

What can be a problem?

Comment: You're going to have all kinds of issues on an OS that old - expired certificates, lack of TLS 1.2 amongst the most debilitating. It's not even the highest OS you could get on that Mac… whatever Mac it is. You ought to be able to update to at least El Capitan, hopefully Sierra, which should at least get you past those major hurdles. We need to know *precisely* what Mac you have.

Comment: I have MacBook Pro (Retina, 15-inch, Mid 2015). Thanks you for the reply! I will try to update my Mac to newer version.

Comment: Good grief! That's probably not been updated since it was new. You *can* upgrade that all the way to Monterey [almost the latest OS, but it will afterwards fall behind again] though I wouldn't do it all in one jump. I would definitely do it in stages - El Capitan, High Sierra, Catalina, then finally Monterey. You will find many big changes along the way. Doing it 'in bits' will help you cope. Trying to do it in one jump would be a nightmare. See https://apple.stackexchange.com/q/309399/85275 and make sure all important data is backed up first.

Comment: Thank you! I will try it.